# Custom mkString function for Scala Iterator

Tags: scala

Given an `Iterator[String]` it is easy enough to create a csv `String` use mkString:

```
//Result: "1,2,3,4,5"
Iterator("1","2","3","4","5").mkString(",")
```

The problem with mkString is that it will consume memory to hold the entire resulting String.

**Is it possible to apply a transform to the original Iterator that gives the same output as mkString but doesn't tie up memory with the entire result?**

```
val csvIter : Iterator[String] = doSomething(Iterator("1","2","3","4","5"))
```

For testing purposes the following expression should return true:

```
val originalIter : Iterator[String] = ???

originalIter.mkString(",") == doSomething(originalIter).reduceOption(_ + _).getOrElse("")
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: `iterator.map(_ + ",")`?

Comment: @Dima That solutions leaves a lingering `,` after the last element.  mkString does not have this flaw...

Comment: would you allow `Iterator("1", ",2", ",3", ...)`?

Comment: Well, this is kinda cheating, but works: `val it = Iterator(1,2,3,4,5); it.map(_ + (if(it.hasNext) "," else ""))`

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet Definitely.  I'll revise my question to accommodate..

Comment: Can this be ok for you? `lazy val myAwesomeString = iterator.mkString(",")`

Comment: @mfirry Unfortunately no.  This simply delays memory consumption, it doesn't eliminate it.  I'm trying to keep memory allocation down to 2 elements in the Iterator, which I **believe** is the minimal amount necessary to accomplisht the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that deals with the first element before treating all the others:

```
def mkString(it: Iterator[String]) = if (it.hasNext)
  Iterator(it.next()) ++ it.map("," + _)
else it
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Beware that you should never reuse `it` afterwards, since it is considered consumed by `map`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it matters to you, but this will interleave the separator as distinct elements:

```
def mkString(iter: Iterator[String], sep: String) = new Iterator[String] {
  var nextIsSep = false
  def hasNext: Boolean = iter.hasNext
  def next(): String = {
    val result = if (nextIsSep) sep else iter.next()
    nextIsSep = !nextIsSep
    result
  }
}
```